# image map area unable to fire click event.afer maximize the widow or restore the window click event firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with image map  i am taken two buttons in my image. in button click one popup(div)displaying .in that div i am taken image one map with areas . i am trying to click (close button and on and off button)) but not responding .after maximize the browser window  it is working . could any one solve this problem.and i want make all images responsive i used [JQuery Image Map](http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html) it is working but . when i given  div position is absolute.
it is not working. can any one provide solution for this problem
(press tab key for identify image map area's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is hard to understand, i will try my best for 50 reps (I am young and needed the money ;)

You are using a JQuery Library from here:
https://raw.github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps/master/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js

The readme of it prints in large letters:
"Allows image maps to be used in a responsive design by recalculating the area coordinates to match the actual image size on load and window.resize"

So, your close handler doesnt trigger, because the area coords were only calculated by that "rwd" once you resize your browser window, and the readme tells us, that it is designed to do so.

Btw to make your code work:
add $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps(); below line 20 in your javascript code.

Comment: Hi, finally i understand the problem with your help.but i added that code in the line 20 it is not working still i am getting same problem... May be your young in rep but your too old in problem understanding :)

Comment: Your click handlers are triggering correctly for me: see here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LuspK. At least i can open those Popups and can close it right away without a window resize.

Comment: yes for your it's working fine. but some where i get problem in my image. but i need a help form you . how can make responsive displaying maintenance panel and hydraulic panel could you suggest me. thanks in advance.